# Convert one character in a C array to uppercase gives C4244 warning

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, toupper

Here is my code where I want to convert just ONE character in the string to uppercase.

```
TCHAR sPassword[16] = L"password";
INT iChar = toupper(sPassword[4]);
sPassword[4] = iChar;
```

It runs correctly, but I get a warning:

```
warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'int' to '_Ty', possible loss of data
```

I tried casting `iChar` with `(INT)` but it made no difference.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Try: `sPassword[4] = (TCHAR)iChar;`

Comment: I'd rate this question as a good [mcve] with tersely stated results and goals.  True that it would benefit with some #includes for `TCHAR, INT`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Warning is due to the narrowing of an `INT` object to a `TCHAR` one.  Theses types exist to afford certainly fixability and may be the like range with other compilations settings.

`TCHAR iChar = (TCHAR) toupper(sPassword[4]);` as answered by [@Zsigmond Szabó](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65643787/2410359) is a good idea - when `TCHAR` is a `char` or friends.

Yet there lies a deeper issue: `toupper()` is for single byte case conversion and is not the best conversion function to use when `TCHAR` is not `char` or the like.

Code might have as well been:

```
int iChar = toupper(sPassword[4]);  // if toupper must be used
sPassword[4] = (TCHAR) iChar;
```

To handle generally `TCHAR` case conversion, code needs more flexibility.

---

`TCHAR` is not a standard C type nor definition.

Assuming this is a MS `TCHAR`, consider [`_totupper()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/toupper-toupper-towupper-toupper-l-towupper-l?view=msvc-160).

```
TCHAR iChar =  (TCHAR) _totupper(sPassword[4]);
sPassword[4] = iChar;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a warning because TCHAR is a `char` (1 byte) and `iChar` is an `int` (most likely 4 bytes). In order to assign an integer to a char, it has to truncate that `int` in order to fit in the `char`, which obviously loses 3 bytes worth of data. You can get rid of the error by explicitly casting `iChar` to a `TCHAR`, like this:

```
sPassword[4] = (TCHAR) iChar;
```

Or, you can declare `iChar` as a `TCHAR`, and do the conversion when you assign it, like this:

```
TCHAR iChar = (TCHAR) toupper(sPassword[4]);
```